how to change font size for tables in eisvogel template?
Pandoc version: 2.9.2.1 
Eisvogel template version: 2.5.0

Note: I asked this question on tex.stackexchange.com and was referred here for the larger pandoc community.
Looking for how to change the font size for tables in the eisvogel template used with pandoc to generate PDF from Markdown.
I have my Markdown file with a table in it but would like to reduce the font size in the table.
Here is how pandoc is being executed -
#!/bin/bash

MARKDOWN_FILE=$1

PDF_FILE=$(basename $MARKDOWN_FILE .md).pdf

pandoc $MARKDOWN_FILE \
        --standalone \
        --template eisvogel \
        --listings \
        --variable listings-disable-line-numbers=true \
        --variable code-block-font-size=\\scriptsize \
        --variable table-use-row-colors=true \
        --variable geometry:margin=1in \
        --variable linkcolor=blue \
        --output $PDF_FILE


The variable settings table-use-row-colors and code-block-font-size=\scriptsize are working as expected but I have not been able to find a way to reduce the font size for the table.
In case it's not obvious my tex/latex skills are minimal.  :)
Here is a minimum working example Markdown document with the font size of the code block reduced from \small to \scriptsize as desired but can't figure out how to reduce the table font size -
# MWE - minimum working example

MWE illustrating code block and table font size adjustments.

Here is a code block -

    my
    code
    block

And here is a table -

| col1  | col2                     | col3                                           |
|:-----:|--------------------------|------------------------------------------------|
|  10   | `ten`                    | row 1 text                                     |
|  11   | `eleven`                 | row 2 text                                     |
|  12   | `twelve`                 | row 3 text                                     |


Here is the generated .tex -
%%
% Copyright (c) 2017 - 2024, Pascal Wagler;
% Copyright (c) 2014 - 2024, John MacFarlane
%
% All rights reserved.
%
% Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
% modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
% are met:
%
% - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
% notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
%
% - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
% notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
% documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
%
% - Neither the name of John MacFarlane nor the names of other
% contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
% from this software without specific prior written permission.
%
% THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
% "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
% LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
% FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
% COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
% INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
% BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
% LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
% CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
% LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
% ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
% POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
%%

%%
% This is the Eisvogel pandoc LaTeX template.
%
% For usage information and examples visit the official GitHub page:
% https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template
%%

% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  paper=a4,
  ,captions=tableheading
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
% Use setspace anyway because we change the default line spacing.
% The spacing is changed early to affect the titlepage and the TOC.
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{default-linkcolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-filecolor}{HTML}{A50000}
\definecolor{default-citecolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\definecolor{default-urlcolor}{HTML}{4077C0}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\passthrough}[1]{#1}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[5.3]Lua}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[x86masm]Assembler}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
% add backlinks to footnote references, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302266/make-footnote-clickable-both-ways
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\usepackage{bookmark}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor={blue},
  filecolor={default-filecolor},
  citecolor={default-citecolor},
  urlcolor={default-urlcolor},
  breaklinks=true,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc with the Eisvogel template}}
\author{}
\date{}



%%
%% added
%%


%
% for the background color of the title page
%

%
% break urls
%
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

%
% When using babel or polyglossia with biblatex, loading csquotes is recommended
% to ensure that quoted texts are typeset according to the rules of your main language.
%
\usepackage{csquotes}

%
% captions
%
\definecolor{caption-color}{HTML}{777777}
\usepackage[font={stretch=1.2}, textfont={color=caption-color}, position=top, skip=4mm, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright]{caption}
\setcapindent{0em}

%
% blockquote
%
\definecolor{blockquote-border}{RGB}{221,221,221}
\definecolor{blockquote-text}{RGB}{119,119,119}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false,topline=false,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=blockquote-border,skipabove=\parskip]{customblockquote}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{customblockquote}\list{}{\rightmargin=0em\leftmargin=0em}%
\item\relax\color{blockquote-text}\ignorespaces}{\unskip\unskip\endlist\end{customblockquote}}

%
% Source Sans Pro as the default font family
% Source Code Pro for monospace text
%
% 'default' option sets the default
% font family to Source Sans Pro, not \sfdefault.
%
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
    \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
  \usepackage{sourcecodepro}
  \else % if not pdftex
    \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
  \usepackage{sourcecodepro}

  % XeLaTeX specific adjustments for straight quotes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354887
  % This issue is already fixed (see https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcecodepro/pull/5) but the
  % fix is still unreleased.
  % TODO: Remove this workaround when the new version of sourcecodepro is released on CTAN.
  \ifxetex
    \makeatletter
    \defaultfontfeatures[\ttfamily]
      { Numbers   = \sourcecodepro@figurestyle,
        Scale     = \SourceCodePro@scale,
        Extension = .otf }
    \setmonofont
      [ UprightFont    = *-\sourcecodepro@regstyle,
        ItalicFont     = *-\sourcecodepro@regstyle It,
        BoldFont       = *-\sourcecodepro@boldstyle,
        BoldItalicFont = *-\sourcecodepro@boldstyle It ]
      {SourceCodePro}
    \makeatother
  \fi
  \fi

%
% heading color
%
\definecolor{heading-color}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{heading-color}}
% When using the classes report, scrreprt, book,
% scrbook or memoir, uncomment the following line.
%\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{heading-color}}

%
% variables for title, author and date
%
\usepackage{titling}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

%
% tables
%

\definecolor{table-row-color}{HTML}{F5F5F5}
\definecolor{table-rule-color}{HTML}{999999}

%\arrayrulecolor{black!40}
\arrayrulecolor{table-rule-color}     % color of \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.3ex}      % thickness of \toprule, \bottomrule
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}     % spacing (padding)

% Unfortunately the colored cells extend beyond the edge of the
% table because pandoc uses @-expressions (@{}) like so:
%
% \begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
% \end{longtable}
%
% https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{2}{}{table-row-color!100}}
\preto{\toprule}{\hiderowcolors}{}{}
\appto{\endhead}{\showrowcolors}{}{}
\appto{\endfirsthead}{\showrowcolors}{}{}

%
% remove paragraph indentation
%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines

%
%
% Listings
%
%


%
% general listing colors
%
\definecolor{listing-background}{HTML}{F7F7F7}
\definecolor{listing-rule}{HTML}{B3B2B3}
\definecolor{listing-numbers}{HTML}{B3B2B3}
\definecolor{listing-text-color}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{listing-keyword}{HTML}{435489}
\definecolor{listing-keyword-2}{HTML}{1284CA} % additional keywords
\definecolor{listing-keyword-3}{HTML}{9137CB} % additional keywords
\definecolor{listing-identifier}{HTML}{435489}
\definecolor{listing-string}{HTML}{00999A}
\definecolor{listing-comment}{HTML}{8E8E8E}

\lstdefinestyle{eisvogel_listing_style}{
  language         = java,
  xleftmargin      = 0.6em,
  framexleftmargin = 0.4em,
  backgroundcolor  = \color{listing-background},
  basicstyle       = \color{listing-text-color}\linespread{1.0}%
                      \lst@ifdisplaystyle%
                      \footnotesize%
                      \fi\ttfamily{},
  breaklines       = true,
  frame            = single,
  framesep         = 0.19em,
  rulecolor        = \color{listing-rule},
  frameround       = ffff,
  tabsize          = 4,
  numberstyle      = \color{listing-numbers},
  aboveskip        = 1.0em,
  belowskip        = 0.1em,
  abovecaptionskip = 0em,
  belowcaptionskip = 1.0em,
  keywordstyle     = {\color{listing-keyword}\bfseries},
  keywordstyle     = {[2]\color{listing-keyword-2}\bfseries},
  keywordstyle     = {[3]\color{listing-keyword-3}\bfseries\itshape},
  sensitive        = true,
  identifierstyle  = \color{listing-identifier},
  commentstyle     = \color{listing-comment},
  stringstyle      = \color{listing-string},
  showstringspaces = false,
  escapeinside     = {/*@}{@*/}, % Allow LaTeX inside these special comments
  literate         =
  {├í}{{\'a}}1 {├⌐}{{\'e}}1 {├¡}{{\'i}}1 {├│}{{\'o}}1 {├║}{{\'u}}1
  {├ü}{{\'A}}1 {├ë}{{\'E}}1 {├ì}{{\'I}}1 {├ô}{{\'O}}1 {├Ü}{{\'U}}1
  {├á}{{\`a}}1 {├¿}{{\`e}}1 {├¼}{{\`i}}1 {├▓}{{\`o}}1 {├╣}{{\`u}}1
  {├Ç}{{\`A}}1 {├ê}{{\`E}}1 {├î}{{\`I}}1 {├Æ}{{\`O}}1 {├Ö}{{\`U}}1
  {├ñ}{{\"a}}1 {├½}{{\"e}}1 {├»}{{\"i}}1 {├╢}{{\"o}}1 {├╝}{{\"u}}1
  {├ä}{{\"A}}1 {├ï}{{\"E}}1 {├Å}{{\"I}}1 {├û}{{\"O}}1 {├£}{{\"U}}1
  {├ó}{{\^a}}1 {├¬}{{\^e}}1 {├«}{{\^i}}1 {├┤}{{\^o}}1 {├╗}{{\^u}}1
  {├é}{{\^A}}1 {├è}{{\^E}}1 {├Ä}{{\^I}}1 {├ö}{{\^O}}1 {├¢}{{\^U}}1
  {┼ô}{{\oe}}1 {┼Æ}{{\OE}}1 {├ª}{{\ae}}1 {├å}{{\AE}}1 {├ƒ}{{\ss}}1
  {├º}{{\c c}}1 {├ç}{{\c C}}1 {├╕}{{\o}}1 {├Ñ}{{\r a}}1 {├à}{{\r A}}1
  {Γé¼}{{\EUR}}1 {┬ú}{{\pounds}}1 {┬½}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {┬╗}{{\guillemotright}}1 {├▒}{{\~n}}1 {├æ}{{\~N}}1 {┬┐}{{?`}}1
  {ΓÇª}{{\ldots}}1 {ΓëÑ}{{>=}}1 {Γëñ}{{<=}}1 {ΓÇ₧}{{\glqq}}1 {ΓÇ£}{{\grqq}}1
  {ΓÇ¥}{{''}}1
}
\lstset{style=eisvogel_listing_style}

%
% Java (Java SE 12, 2019-06-22)
%
\lstdefinelanguage{Java}{
  morekeywords={
    % normal keywords (without data types)
    abstract,assert,break,case,catch,class,continue,default,
    do,else,enum,exports,extends,final,finally,for,if,implements,
    import,instanceof,interface,module,native,new,package,private,
    protected,public,requires,return,static,strictfp,super,switch,
    synchronized,this,throw,throws,transient,try,volatile,while,
    % var is an identifier
    var
  },
  morekeywords={[2] % data types
    % primitive data types
    boolean,byte,char,double,float,int,long,short,
    % String
    String,
    % primitive wrapper types
    Boolean,Byte,Character,Double,Float,Integer,Long,Short
    % number types
    Number,AtomicInteger,AtomicLong,BigDecimal,BigInteger,DoubleAccumulator,DoubleAdder,LongAccumulator,LongAdder,Short,
    % other
    Object,Void,void
  },
  morekeywords={[3] % literals
    % reserved words for literal values
    null,true,false,
  },
  sensitive,
  morecomment  = [l]//,
  morecomment  = [s]{/*}{*/},
  morecomment  = [s]{/**}{*/},
  morestring   = [b]",
  morestring   = [b]',
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  morestring      = [b]",
  moredelim       = [s][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{<}{\ },
  moredelim       = [s][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{</}{>},
  moredelim       = [l][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{/>},
  moredelim       = [l][\bfseries\color{listing-keyword}]{>},
  morecomment     = [s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment     = [s]{<!--}{-->},
  commentstyle    = \color{listing-comment},
  stringstyle     = \color{listing-string},
  identifierstyle = \color{listing-identifier}
}

%
% header and footer
%
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newpairofpagestyles{eisvogel-header-footer}{
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ihead*{}
  \chead*{}
  \ohead*{}
  \ifoot*{}
  \cfoot*{}
  \ofoot*{\thepage}
  \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
}
\pagestyle{eisvogel-header-footer}



%%
%% end added
%%

\begin{document}

%%
%% begin titlepage
%%

%%
%% end titlepage
%%



\hypertarget{mwe---minimum-working-example}{%
\section{MWE - minimum working
example}\label{mwe---minimum-working-example}}

MWE illustrating code block and table font size adjustments.

Here is a code block -

\begin{lstlisting}
my
code
block
\end{lstlisting}

And here is a table -

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}cll@{}}
\toprule
col1 & col2 & col3\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
10 & \passthrough{\lstinline!ten!} & row 1 text\tabularnewline
11 & \passthrough{\lstinline!eleven!} & row 2 text\tabularnewline
12 & \passthrough{\lstinline!twelve!} & row 3 text\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


Maybe add \AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny}

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I was hoping to find a setting within eisvogel template as this approach sounds like I would need to edit the generated .tex file and then continue processing it.  Those steps are beyond my current skill set.
So I tried adding that to my generated .tex file at line 419 (right before the table as far as I can tell) and then ran "pdflatex mwe.tex".  It generated a lot of messages that looked like errors but it did generate a PDF file and the font in the table header was \tiny though the table rows were back to their default.

After reviewing that .tex file and the eisvogel template I am coming to the conclusion that what I am looking for is an enhancement to the eisvogel template to add a variable "table-font-size" similar to the "code-block-font-size" already implemented.
And given the longtable change and its effect it almost sounds like a "table-header-font-size" and "table-row-font-size" might be possible.

You can also use the --include-in-header options (or similar) to add some raw latex (if the template does have such a variable). See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

I think you can simply stick \AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny} at the start of your markdown document
